# js Fetch() esperar respuesta, para test eco en servidor

Tags: javascript, nodejs, http, fetch, server

Estoy jugueteando con el modulo http de node. solo quiero dos tubos, para subir y bajar datos, la charla la inicia la pagina. 
Ya tengo un experimento, que funciona, una pagina con un simple input, donde hay que ponerle UN NUMERO, y un boton para enviar por Fetch(). El server lo pilla, le suma 8 y lo devuelve. Lo repilla el Fetch, le suma 2 y lo presenta. (* tanta suma es para comprobar que esta vivo, y al mantenerse las unidades, verifica que no se interfieren entre paginas).
La cosa funciona, lo siguiente es hacerlo en automatico, hacer lo de antes en un bucle while(1). pero esto me vencio, segun el debug de chrome, pasa por fetch, llega a response.text() (* en por boton response tiene datos, en bucle aun una promesa), y salta de regreso al bucle, para nueva vuelta, no suma nada. El servidor canta la peticion. 
probe a poner o no asyn/awais, .them, promises, nada de lo que vi resolvio el problema
`<button id="boton" onclick="BotonClick()">B</button>` cambiar por BotonClick***2***() para hacer en bucle. 
No entiendo como tiro a tiro va bien, y falla en rafaga. (*el html hay que nombrarlo indexLugoSO.html , en mismo dir que le js, y ejecutar en localhost:3001)

```js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require('fs');
const favi = fs.readFileSync('./favicon.ico'); //CARGA EN MEMO EL DIBU DEL FAVICON
let pag = fs.readFileSync('./indexLugoSO.html', 'utf8'); //CARGA EN MEMO LA PAGINA

const server1 = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log();
    console.log("paso por server1");
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.method);
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') { //SI SE USA FAVICON
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/x-icon");//application/octet-stream EN CASO DE BINARIOS
            res.write(favi);
            res.end();
            return; // retures???, a donde???, no seria continue???, misterios de la informatica,,,
        }
        if (req.url === '/') { //CASO index, 
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.write(pag);
            res.end();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (req.method === "POST") { //EN NUESTRO CASO PASA POR AQUI
        if (req.url === '/post/data/here') {
            let dato = '';
            console.log(`STATUS:` + res.statusCode);
            req.on('data', chunk => { //EL ROLLITO DEL CHUNK, 
                console.log('A chunk of data has arrived: ', chunk.toString());
                dato += chunk.toString();// A Q U I  P I L L A  E L  N U M E R I T O
                return;
            });
            req.on('end', () => {
                console.log('No more data');
                res.statusCode = 200;
                console.log('dato: ', dato);
                res.end('' + (parseInt(dato) + 8));// A Q U I  +=8,  Y  E N V I A
                return;
            })
        }
        if (req.url === '/') { //CASO index, no tenia claro si entra por get o por post
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.write(pag);
            res.end();
            return;
        }
    }
}
);

server1.listen(3001, () => { console.log("puerto 3001"); });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,"><!-- NADA DE FAVICONes -->
    <title>ECO TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h6>h6</h6>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="inputId">
    </form>
    <button id="boton" onclick="BotonClick()">B</button>
    <!-- SI PONEMOS BotonClick2(), para que entre en bucle => LIO -->
    <script>
        function BotonClick2() { while (true) { BotonClick(); } }
        async function BotonClick() {
            /* let data2 = `Lorem ipsum dolor `;
            let data3 = ''; while (data3.length < 1000) { data3 += data2; } */  /* antiguo test para chunk */

            let data4 = document.getElementById('inputId').value; //lee el numero en casilla input

            const response = await fetch("/post/data/here", {//lanza un fetch
                method: "POST",                //con estos parametros
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
                body: data4 //CON LO LEIDO EN INPUT
            })
            const text = await response.text(); //sin asyn/await no sabe que es text en response, (response es promesa aun)
            //EN TIRO A TIRO LLEGA AQUI, Y PASA, EN BUCLE NO PASA DE AQUI. 
            console.log("Request complete! response:", text);  //LE LLEGA
            document.getElementById('inputId').value = '' + (parseInt(text) + 2); //LE SUMA 2, Y ESCRIBE, el servidor le sumo 8, =10
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

LO ENCONTRE !!!. 
hay que cambiar

```
function BotonClick2() { while (true) { BotonClick(); } }
```

por

```
async function BotonClick2() { while (true) { await BotonClick(); } }
```

y si se quiere que funcione en bucle, como explique,
`<button id="boton" onclick="BotonClick()">B</button>` cambiar por BotonClick***2***() 
Segun pruebas, me da unos 150 refrescos de pag /s, repartidos en 4 paginas, en un lenovo normalito de 4 nucleos. Segun el admin de tareas, la cpu llega al 100%
 Aunque la verdad, no tengo muy claro lo que estoy haciendo,,,